# Vertically aligning tabular cell contents with respect to one another

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have a simple table that can be recreated with the simple MWE below, I am compiling with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=19mm, right=19mm, top=3.52cm, bottom=2.84cm, headheight=38.7pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.15}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{@{}m{4.4cm}m{12.5cm}@{}}
\hline
\textbf{TO:} & Mr.\noindent and Mrs.\noindent J. Doe \\[0.54cm]
\hline
\textbf{SUBJECT:} & This is just a sample subject that is design to illustrate the text wrapping\\[0.54cm]
\hline
\textbf{DATE:} & \today \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following table:

[image]

As you can see in the first two rows, the contents of the cells next to one another aren't vertically aligned by their respective centres, I've added `hline`s to make this obvious. How can I centre them properly?

Comment: Just remove those `\\[.54cm]`. What are they for?

Comment: I was using those to set an empty space between rows of the table. Is there a better way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to increase the height of the rows, you should go via `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<someFactor>}`.

```
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=19mm, right=19mm, top=3.52cm, bottom=2.84cm, headheight=38.7pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.15}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % adjust value to your needs
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}m{4.4cm}m{12.95cm}@{}} % increased to maximum width
    \toprule
    \textbf{TO:} & Mr.\ and Mrs.\ J.~Doe \\%\addlinespace % if you need some space after your row
    \midrule
    \textbf{SUBJECT:} & This is just a sample subject that is design to illustrate the text wrapping\\
    \midrule
    \textbf{DATE:} & \today \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}   
\end{document}
```

[image]